# Finish leaves activity in stack

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity that performs a small bit of code and then calls finish. This works fine and the activity goes away, but if I press the history button (if it's called the history button?) the activity still appears to be there, though clicking it will do nothing.

I have enabled `android:noHistory="true"` in my manifest. I only have a single activity that changes some settings, and then calls finish, nothing else.

Is there a way for me to make that trace of the activity go away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the history button you refer to is the list of recent apps, you can set

`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

By default value for this attribute is false.

For other attributes check the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html